# Query on my sql db

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two different query:

```
SELECT Nazione,
       count(*) as Gold
  FROM `SummerTotalMedal` 
 where Medaglia = 'gold'
   and Sport = 'Athletics' 
 group by Nazione
 order by Gold DESC
```

and

```
SELECT Nazione, 
       count(*) as Silver
  FROM `SummerTotalMedal` 
 where Medaglia = 'silver'
   and Sport = 'Athletics' 
 group by Nazione
 order by Silver DESC
```

Is there a way to join this query such that I get the two different output on two different coloumns?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation for the same

```
select 
Nazione,
sum(case when Medaglia ='gold' and Sport='Athletics' then 1 else 0 end) as Gold,
sum(case when Medaglia ='silver' and Sport='Athletics' then 1 else 0 end) as Silver
from SummerTotalMedal
group by Nazione
```

Comment: you can get that even shorter since `Medaglia ='gold' and Sport='Athletics'` itself will evaluate to 0 or 1, so you do not need the `case when`and `then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Yes that only works for mysql but for other RDBMS you need to use this standard ANSI format

Comment: Yes , it is. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is `IF` function in MySQL:

```
SELECT Nazione,
    sum(IF(Medaglia ='gold', 1, 0)) as Gold,
    sum(IF(Medaglia ='silver', 1, 0)) as Silver
FROM SummerTotalMedal
WHERE Sport='Athletics'
GROUP BY Nazione
```